# How do you generate random numbers(say 2^100) with repeated numbers randomly distributed with some variable percentage to control repeat?

Tags: math, random, distribution

For Ex: say you generate one million numbers out of 2^100 numbers and 10% of a million should be repeated numbers from 90% of one million random numbers and this 10% repeat should be **randomly distributed** in one million numbers.

Comment: Start by calculating 2^100 for us.

Comment: 1) Generate 900000 random numbers. 2) Copy first 100000 numbers from this list to the end of this list, now you have a list of mln numbers. 3) Shuffle the list.

Answer (score 0):

First, start generating 1 million 100bit random values. You can do it quite easily using a PRNG function